# Internationalization for datetime

Tags: python, postgresql, internationalization, datetime-format, datetimeoffset

I am building a mobile app and would like to follow best practice for datetime. Initially, we launched it in India and made our server, database and app time to IST.

Now we are launching the app to other countries(timezones), how should I store the datetime? Should the server time be set to UTC and app should display time-based on user's timezone?

What's the best practice to follow in terms of storing date time and exchanging date time format between client and server? Should the client send date time in UTC to the server or in it's own timezone along with locale?

Comment: I think you should store the data in UTC and show it in local time (managed in the UI).

Comment: ["_All timezone-aware dates and times are stored internally in UTC. They are converted to local time in the zone specified by the TimeZone configuration parameter before being displayed to the client._"](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-TIMEZONES)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep as much in UTC as possible.  Do your timezone conversion at your edges (client display and input processing), but keep anything stored server side in UTC.